# about the usage of somebody and anyone

Tags: word-usage

I have a question about something which is on my mind for a while.
I was watching an instagram story and the man was speaking English. I'm going to quote directly what he said. ( he spreads positiveness by the way.)

He : Somebody gon' love you man don't think so bitter stay positive. I'm not scared to tell nobody I love them I love every people in the world.

So.. my questions are the "gon" and "nobody" parts. First, after somebody we need to use "is"? I don't know I couldn't find anything suffice me on the internet.
And second question is about somebody, someone, nobody, anybody, anyone I don't know how to use these words properly. If someone helps I really appreciate that.

Addition : I'm sorry if I did any spelling or punctuation mistakes. I'm trying to  get better

Comment: "Somebody gon" is short for "Somebody is going to". And the use of "nobody" in negative sentences, instead of "somebody" (or "anybody"), is quite commonly used for emphasis in informal speech.

Comment: Well said, James. This question probably belongs on our sister site for English Language Learners, where you might receive additional help. The quoted sentences you've posted are **not** examples of "proper" English usage (even though I chafe at suggesting there even is such a thing), so they should not be emulated at this point until you understand their colloquial nature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, you're correct."Somebody" should be followed by "is" because his use of "gon'" is an oral abbreviation of "gonna" or "going to." In summary, the correct phrasing would be something like "Somebody is going to love you, man."

As for your second question, *somebody* and *someone* are interchangable. Both indicate a specific individual and usually just one like in this example.

> Someone make me a sandwich!

But could refer to one or more, like in this example.

> Somebody help me!

*Anybody* and *anyone* function similarly, except it generally includes a larger pool of people and usually means more than one.

> Anybody want to play frisbee?

But could also mean one.

> I need someone else to join the cast of my short film. Anyone will do.

*Nobody* or *no one* mean the opposite:

> Nobody come in here; I'm changing!
>
> No one wants to play frisbee today, so I'll stay home and watch Netflix.

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel I really understand.

Comment: Great, I'm so happy to have helped!